# Game disconnects when I click on the town hall

Tags: clash-of-clans

As of the new update, my game will automatically disconnect if I click my town hall. I can no longer upgrade my town hall, etc.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks daniel. Do you know how to fix that problem?

Comment: No sorry I do not, I guess your best and maybe only bet is to wait until they patched it. Maybe you could send their support an email?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the game yet? it might be that your patch got corrutped. So either download it again or use the repair function if it exists. Don't forget to make an account so you don't lose your data uninstalling the game (but you've already done an account else you're just  crazy :D )

Comment: It seems like the new update is causing a lot of problems...

Comment: I already uninstall the game. I even reset my phone. Still it didnt fix. I even use another phone and log in my gmail account. Still the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently [a known issue, acknowledged by Supercell.](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/934438-Town-Hall-11-update-Bugs-Problems-thread) See the third item in their bug list for the TH11 update.

I would expect a patch on this shortly from Supercell.

*Also note: Supercell has ended support for devices with iOS versions lower than 5.1.1*